# Como centralizar um componente usando null layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout

o meu botao que quero centralizar tem 100 pixels de largura. a Jframe tem 350 de largura. como centralizar?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ComboBoxLUL;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Igor
 */
public class PainelPrincipal extends JPanel {

    private JComboBox jcbGenero;

    private JComboBox jcbCasado;

    private JButton btnSalva;

    private JLabel lblNome;

    private JLabel lblIdade;

    private JLabel lblCpf;

    private JTextField txtCpf;

    private JTextField txtNome;

    private JTextField txtIdade;

    private final String[] genero = {"Masculino ", "Feminino"};

    private final String[] estCivil = {"Casado", "Solteiro"};

    // private Integer[] genero = {1,2,3};// essa forma funciona. int nao. mas o resultado é o msm.

    PainelPrincipal() {
        this.setLayout(null);

        txtNome = new JTextField();
        txtNome.setBounds(45, 90, 120, 25);
        this.add(txtNome);
        ///////////
        txtCpf = new JTextField();
        txtCpf.setBounds(45, 50, 120, 25);
        this.add(txtCpf);
        ///////////
        txtIdade = new JTextField();
        txtIdade.setBounds(45, 130, 120, 25);
        this.add(txtIdade);

        //////////
        lblCpf = new JLabel("CPF");
        lblCpf.setBounds(10, 50, 120, 25);
        this.add(lblCpf);
        //////////

        lblIdade = new JLabel("Idade");
        lblIdade.setBounds(10,90,120,25);
        this.add(lblIdade);

        lblNome = new JLabel("Nome");
        lblNome.setBounds(10, 130, 120, 25);
        this.add(lblNome);

        jcbGenero = new JComboBox(genero);
        jcbGenero.setBounds(170, 50, 120, 25);
        this.add(jcbGenero);

        jcbCasado = new JComboBox(estCivil);
        jcbCasado.setBounds(170, 90, 120, 25);
        this.add(jcbCasado);

        btnSalva = new JButton("Salvar");
        btnSalva.setBounds(175, 175, 100, 25);
        this.add(btnSalva);

        btnSalva.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
            }

        });
        this.add(btnSalva);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só usar um pouco de matemática: se a tela tem 350px de largura total e o componente tem 100, para ele ocupar uma porção central, a posição horizontal dele na tela é:

> (larguraDatela/2) - (larguraDoComponente/2)

Aplicando esse cálculo com os dados informados resulta:

> 350/2 - 100/2 = 125

Este 125 é a posição horizontal de onde o seu botão deveria ser posicionado no `setBounds`. Veja:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Igor
 */
public class PainelPrincipal extends JPanel {

    private JComboBox jcbGenero;

    private JComboBox jcbCasado;

    private JButton btnSalva;

    private JLabel lblNome;

    private JLabel lblIdade;

    private JLabel lblCpf;

    private JTextField txtCpf;

    private JTextField txtNome;

    private JTextField txtIdade;

    private final String[] genero = {"Masculino ", "Feminino"};

    private final String[] estCivil = {"Casado", "Solteiro"};

    // private Integer[] genero = {1,2,3};// essa forma funciona. int nao. mas o resultado é o msm.
    PainelPrincipal() {
        this.setLayout(null);

        txtNome = new JTextField();
        txtNome.setBounds(45, 90, 120, 25);
        this.add(txtNome);
        ///////////
        txtCpf = new JTextField();
        txtCpf.setBounds(45, 50, 120, 25);
        this.add(txtCpf);
        ///////////
        txtIdade = new JTextField();
        txtIdade.setBounds(45, 130, 120, 25);
        this.add(txtIdade);

        //////////
        lblCpf = new JLabel("CPF");
        lblCpf.setBounds(10, 50, 120, 25);
        this.add(lblCpf);
        //////////

        lblIdade = new JLabel("Idade");
        lblIdade.setBounds(10, 90, 120, 25);
        this.add(lblIdade);

        lblNome = new JLabel("Nome");
        lblNome.setBounds(10, 130, 120, 25);
        this.add(lblNome);

        jcbGenero = new JComboBox(genero);
        jcbGenero.setBounds(170, 50, 120, 25);
        this.add(jcbGenero);

        jcbCasado = new JComboBox(estCivil);
        jcbCasado.setBounds(170, 90, 120, 25);
        this.add(jcbCasado);

        btnSalva = new JButton("Salvar");
        // btnSalva.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        // JPanel btnPan = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        // btnPan.add(btnSalva);
        // this.add(btnPan);
        btnSalva.setBounds(125, 175, 100, 25);
        this.add(btnSalva);

        btnSalva.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
            }

        });
        this.add(btnSalva);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.getContentPane().add(new PainelPrincipal(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350));
                f.pack();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

---

Mas como sugestão, **evite sempre usar layout absoluto**. Ele dificulta a manutenção da interface, pois quaisquer mudanças futuras você terá que sair reposicionando todos os componentes manualmente, imagine uma tela com dezenas desses? Sem contar que, dependendo da resolução e tamanho do monitor, sua interface pode se apresentar diferente do que você programou. Leia sobre [**LayoutManager**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), há várias opções nativas e outras muito boas da comunidade, e o melhor é que você pode mesclar todos eles.

Segue alguns links a respeito de LayoutManager:

- [Mais Swing: layout managers, mais componentes e detalhes](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/mais-swing-layout-managers-mais-componentes-e-detalhes/)
- [Conhecendo Gerenciadores de Layout GUI do Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conhecendo-gerenciadores-de-layout-gui-do-java/25869)

Comment: **evite usar layout absoluto**. +1

Comment: realmente era mt facil. fui dormir pensando e acordei com a resposta. é a metade da tela menos a metade do componente xD

Comment: @IgorAugusto mesmo assim, da uma pesquisada sobre layouts managers, eles são bem mais interessantes, posicionar na mao componente por componente é fria meu amigo kkkkk

Comment: sim. sou iniciante. tinha mt medo de layouts prontos. sempre sonhei em fazer tudo na mao. mas demora muito. vou pesquisar sim. qual vc me indica? que tenha certo controle como o metodo setBounds? arrastar botoes no netbenas quase me levaram ao suicidio. da mt problema kkkk

Comment: @IgorAugusto no link da pergunta tem os principais do java, geralmente eles são suficientes, se sacar como cada um funciona. Nesse link explica um pouco de cada um: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/mais-swing-layout-managers-mais-componentes-e-detalhes/

Comment: @IgorAugusto se a resposta lhe ajudou a solucionar, você pode aceita-la, clicando no `v` a esquerda, dessa forma ela servirá de referencia para outras pessoas :)